# How to plot a gray color density plot

Tags: plotting

This is suppose to be a simple task but I can not get a simple gray scale density plot. I have tried the color function, but can not get to the one that plots in gray scale or just one color

```
DensityPlot[Sin[Pi*x - Pi], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> {1500, 500}, 
  AspectRatio -> Full, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", Mesh -> 30]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
DensityPlot[Sin[Pi*x - Pi], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> {1500, 500}, 
 AspectRatio -> Full, ColorFunction -> "GrayTones", Mesh -> 30]
```

[image: Out]

or

```
DensityPlot[Sin[Pi*x - Pi], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> {1500, 500}, 
 AspectRatio -> Full, ColorFunction -> "MonochromeFractalGradient", Mesh -> 30]
```

[image: MonochromeFractalGradient]

or

```
DensityPlot[Sin[Pi*x - Pi], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> {1500, 500}, 
 AspectRatio -> Full, ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[#] &), Mesh -> 30]
```

[image]

for gray scale, and

```
DensityPlot[Sin[Pi*x - Pi], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> {1500, 500}, 
 AspectRatio -> Full, ColorFunction -> (Lighter[Blue, #] &), Mesh -> 30]
```

[image]

or

```
DensityPlot[Sin[Pi*x - Pi], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> {1500, 500}, 
 AspectRatio -> Full, ColorFunction -> (Opacity[1 - #, Blue] &), Mesh -> 30]
```

[image]

or

```
DensityPlot[Sin[Pi*x - Pi], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> {1500, 500}, 
 AspectRatio -> Full, ColorFunction -> (LCHColor[#, 1, 0.8] &), Mesh -> 30]
```

[image]

for a single color.

Comment: I am rather surprised that `"GrayTones"` does not produce neutral tones.  I guess I always code my own using `GrayLevel`.

Comment: Please, may you elaborate on not produce neutral tones and settign the Graylevel and where do you set this option?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It's not [`"AchromaticGrays"`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shades_of_gray#Achromatic_grays). "A tone is produced either by the mixture of a color with gray, or ..." [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tints_and_shades) Therefore `"GrayTones"` seems to be an appropriate name. I don't know if `"GrayTones"` are base on a typical gradient, color perception, or color profile, but its basically `GrayLevel` + [warm and cool gray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey#Optics): [ImageAssemple](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ACS3c.png).

Comment: @JoseECalderon Sorry, I don't understand your comment. To my understanding something like "neutral tones" don't really exist, that would be called achromatic grays or just gray (see my comment to Mr. Wizard above). My third example show how and where to set the option to use `GrayLevel` as the `ColorFunction`.

Answer (score 8):

Replace your `ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow"` with `PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Alternatively, one can use `PlotTheme -> "GrayColor"`, which is identical to `PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"`, at least for a `DensityPlot`.

Comment: For "just one color" the corresponding `PlotTheme` would be, for example, `PlotTheme -> {"Monochrome", Blue}`.